# Undesired indentation of commented code in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, indentation

First of all i am using NetBeans IDE 7.1 (Build 201112071828).

I have this piece of code

```
<script>
    onload = function()
    {
        tooltip.init();
        var myTable = new SortedTable();
    }
</script>
```

If if place the cursor at the line `tooltip.init();` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> it comments out this line. If i repeat this combination, the line is uncommented as expected.

Now, if i have commented this piece and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to format my code, the commented line will be indented to the rest of the codeblock like this:

```
<script>
    onload = function()
    {
        //            tooltip.init();
        var myTable = new SortedTable();
    }
</script>
```

This indentation breaks the behavior of the comment shortcut, which will add a second comment at the beginning of the line on press.

Is there any way i can disable indentation of commented code? I have searched the complete `Tools->Options->Editor->Formatting` and was not able to find this setting.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this was possible in 7.1, but definitely works in Netbeans 7.2. You can find it in `Java -> Comments`  - `Enable Comments Formatting`. Disabling `Format Block Comments` should be enough.

[image: netbeans formatting setting]

Answer (score 1):

Open `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Keymap`, then look for the action called "Re-indent current line or Selection" and set whatever shortcut you want.